# Unable to restore sqlite from backup

Tags: android, android-studio, database-backups, database-restore

I have this application for years and after updating the application I found that I could no longer restore the data. I'm able to backup and I can see all data in DB Browser for SQLite on my desktop. When I install the app on a new device, i copy the backup to the same folder and do a restore, no data shows. I get no errors when I restore and I see the data get restored from the right folder when I run in debugging mode in Android Studio.
Haven't changed anything in backup and restore function.

The Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Target SDK 34 Min SDK 28

I tried different Target and Min, but with no luck.

```
private void restoredata(){
    InputStream myInput;
    String dbpath = "/data/com.example.myapp/databases/MyData.db";
    String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
    Boolean FileErr=true;
    try {

        File exist = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + dbpath);
        System.out.println("1 " + exist.exists());

        // Set the output folder on the Scard
        File directory = new File(sdpath + "/MyBack");
        File file = new File(sdpath + "/MyBack/MyBackup.db");
        // Create the folder if it doesn't exist:
        if (!directory.exists() || !directory.isDirectory()) {
            showMyAlert("Folder Download/MyBack not found!");
            FileErr = false;
        } else if (!file.exists()) {
            showMyAlert("File MyBackup.db not found!");
            FileErr = false;
        }


        if (FileErr) {
            // Set the input file stream up:
            try {
                myInput = new FileInputStream(directory.getPath() + "/MyBackup.db");

                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory() + dbpath);

                // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                // Close and clear the streams

                myOutput.flush();

                myOutput.close();

                myInput.close();

                Toast.makeText(SetupPage.this, "Restore Done Succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e){

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: 1. You did not tell how you want to do the restore. 2. You did not tell what went wrong.